# how to find a particular date when there are many dates

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping

I have a data which I collected by web-scraping. In my scraping data, there are the different date in the different format, I need to find a particular date from data so I made a [regular expression](https://regex101.com/r/pOfCC8/3) for python that can find a date from any format.

The regular expression I made is:

```
(?:\w+\/\w+\/\w+|\w+\-\w+\-\w+|\d+\s+\w+\s+\d+)
```

I got the date in correct syntax but the main task is to retrieve a particular date.I have a string in which i used a regular expression like

> The starting date of application is 21/10/2018 and end date is
>   30/10/2018. The application was issued on 10 November 2018

I want to retrieve **start date**, **issued date** and **end date**. Can Somebody help me..

Comment: Hi, would you post the regular expression?

Comment: Do the dates always follow this pattern - Start date, followed by end date, and then issued date ?

Comment: Can you share some sample data and the regular expression for everyone here understand your approach?

Comment: sample data  "xxxxx released the notification on 25 Oct 2018. Application will be started on 10/11/2018 and end on 25 November 2018."
I want to retrieve start date and end date. For start date i made a Positive Lookbehind Regular Expression like \w*(?<=(start))\w*\s*(?:\w+\/\w+\/\w+|\w+\-\w+\-\w+|\d+\s+\w+\s+\d+) but it is not working..

Comment: Can you share HTML source code instead of raw text?

Comment: So this is not always the same pattern?

Comment: Examples sites are
(1) https://www.wisdomjobs.com/govtjobs/karnataka-state-police-recruitment-police-jobs-karnataka-state-police-jobs-2018-09-sub-inspector-wireless-37279
(2) https://www.sarkariresult.com/page/armyrtoct.php
In all the above sites, there are many dates. I want to retrieve particular date using Regular Expression's Lookaround Method.

Comment: You have to know keywords if you don't want to write an AI for this

Comment: Yes, Sites is not always following the same pattern. But Can I used regex using lookaround to find a date using a word (word will be also create using regex)

Comment: So you want to find your keywords via regex?